# For i/number/key in x... where are these variables defined?

Tags: python

I am learning Python's `for` loop system, it is going well but one keep continues to puzzle me.

Frequently I see someone's `for` loop, and it includes the syntax `for x in y`, where `x` *is some variable I never defined*. In the examples below, x would be `number`, `key`, and `i`.

**Example 1:**

```
numbers = 5345
for number in numbers:
```

I defined `numbers`, but I never defined `number`, where did `number` come from?

**Example 2:**

```
keywords = ['banana', 'mango', 'apple']
for key in keywords:
```

I defined `keywords`, but I never defined `key`, where did `key` come from?

**Example 3:**

```
for i in [6423, 2334, 3453, 5234]:
```

I never defined `i`, where did `i` come from?

After reading through a bunch of `for` loop tutorials, I cannot find any explanation of where `number`, `key`, and `i` come from.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Python variables don't need to be declared before assignment

Comment: Python's `for` loop is what some other language call a `foreach` loop; in plain English: "for each `foo` in `bar`, do *something* to `foo`".

Comment: `numbers = 5345;
for number in numbers:` would give you an error i imagine ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You choose them!

When you say `for x in numbers`, Python starts going through `numbers`, assigning each item it finds to the name `x` and allows you to do something with `x`.

You could type literally any variable name there. Think of the name that follows `for` as an assignment, unlike the name following `in` which is a reference.

Try the following code:

```
names = ["Dave", "John", "Sam"]
for x in names:
    print(x)
```

Now change the `x`es to any other variable name you want, and run it again. It still works!

Comment: +1. I think your comparison to assignment makes this easier to understand, because all of the other stuff it implies is true as well (e.g., you can redefine an existing variable by using it as a loop counter, exactly as you can with an assignment statement).

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the variable by using it in a for..in loop. During each iteration of the loop, it is assigned the next element of the sequence. You can call it whatever you wish.

Answer (score 1):

`for` is an *iterator* which does *iteration*

*Iteration* means walking through the *elements* of anything that is *iterable*, in *steps*.

*Iterables* are *sequential containers*, which contain *elements*.

On every *step* we get an *element* in the *sequential container*.

On every *step* that *element* is assigned to what comes after `for` and before `in`, say `x` in `for x in [1,2,3]:`, and through out that *step* i.e. the *body of the loop* (the indented part), that element can be referred with `x`.

On the first step in `for x in [1, 2, 3]`, `x` will be `1`, and `2` and `3` in the second and third step, respectively.

How many steps are there? The number of elements in the sequential container (there could be infinite in case of [generators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/1309352)). In the above case there were *3*.

It's *you*, the *programmer*, who decided what to name the variable that takes in the *element* in each *step* of the *iteration*. It could be `x`, `y`, `foo`, `bar`, `sdfasdfjdiofjasdifjiosdfjiojio`, `_`, anything that Python allows an object/*element*'s referee be named.

*This answer is not supposed to taken to cover all things related. But is intended to create an understanding upon which others related could build.*